# 'WHEN t2.first_name <> '' then CONCAT(t2.first_name,' ',t2.last_name) WHEN t3.fir' at line 7

Tags: mysql

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'WHEN t2.first_name <> '' then CONCAT(t2.first_name,' ',t2.last_name) WHEN t3.fir'` at line 7

```
SELECT t1.*,
    CASE
        WHEN t2.first_name <> '' THEN CONCAT(t2.first_name, ' ', t2.last_name)
        WHEN t3.first_name <> '' then CONCAT(t3.first_name, ' ', t3.last_name)
        ELSE ''
    END AS author
FROM
    (`forum` t1)
    LRGY JOIN `admin_users` t2 ON `t1`.`user_id`=`t2`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `members` t3 ON `t1`.`member_id`=`t3`.`member_id`
WHERE
    `t1`.`member_id` = '104' AND
    `topic` LIKE '%This is a topic%' AND
    `CASE`
        WHEN t2.first_name <> '' THEN CONCAT(t2.first_name,' ',t2.last_name)
        WHEN t3.first_name <> '' then CONCAT(t3.first_name,' ',t3.last_name)
        ELSE ''
     END LIKE '%admin admin%'
```

Filename: /home/wsddev3/public_html/dev/justice/models/forum_model.php

Line Number: 40

Comment: Try formatting your code first. This almost always makes syntax errors obvious.

Comment: It's probably the backticks around the `CASE`. Try removing those.

Comment: @Zagor23 A mistyped `LEFT JOIN` :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue in `CASE` statement in WHERE it has to be without `'`

```
SELECT t1.*,
    CASE
        WHEN t2.first_name <> '' THEN CONCAT(t2.first_name, ' ', t2.last_name)
        WHEN t3.first_name <> '' then CONCAT(t3.first_name, ' ', t3.last_name)
        ELSE ''
    END AS author
FROM
    `forum` t1
    LEFT JOIN `admin_users` t2 ON `t1`.`user_id`=`t2`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `members` t3 ON `t1`.`member_id`=`t3`.`member_id`
WHERE
    `t1`.`member_id` = '104' AND
    `topic` LIKE '%This is a topic%' AND
    CASE
        WHEN t2.first_name <> '' THEN CONCAT(t2.first_name,' ',t2.last_name)
        WHEN t3.first_name <> '' then CONCAT(t3.first_name,' ',t3.last_name)
        ELSE ''
     END LIKE '%admin admin%'
```